# Bootstrap-Vue <b-card /> With Link In Title

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have a component that contains a `<b-card>` component like this:

```
<b-card :title="post.title">
  <p class="card-text">{{ post.body }}</p>
</b-card>
```

How do I make the card title a clickable link? That is, I can set the text with `:title=` but there does not exist a parameter to wrap the text in a `<a href="">` tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can disable the render of `title` and `sub-title` with `no-body` option. Then, you can implement the body yourself.

```
<b-card no-body>
  <b-card-body>
    <b-link to="/">
      <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
    </b-link>
    <p class="card-text">{{ post.body }}</p>
  </b-card-body>
</b-card>
```